# Three.js animate from one position to another

Tags: javascript, three.js

Let's say I have a shape at `position.x = 0` and I want to smoothly animate it in the render loop to `position.x = 2.435`. How would I go about that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your target position as a variable (outside the render loop):

```
var targetPositionX = 2.435;
```

Then in your render loop, create an if statement that checks if the object's `X position` is less than the `targetPositionX`. If it is , it will add an increment (which you can change based on how fast you want it to move) to the object's `X position`. When the object's X position becomes greater or equal to the `targetPositionX`, it will stop moving.

Something like this:

```
if (object.position.x <= targetPositionX) {
    object.position.x += 0.001; // You decide on the increment, higher value will mean the objects moves faster
}
```

Here is the full code for the render loop:

```
function loop(){

    // render the scene
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    // Check the object's X position
    if (object.position.x <= targetPositionX) {
        object.position.x += 0.001; // You decide on the increment, higher value will mean the objects moves faster
    }

    // call the loop function again
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
```

**Side note**

For more detailed/complex animations you may want to look into Tween.js for Three.js which makes animation easier and also allows you to add easing functions to your animation.

You can find it here:

https://github.com/sole/tween.js

I would recommend reading into it if you are getting into Three.js.

Comment: I tried your approach initially but I think I know what I did wrong. The orgin point of the element was not matching with the increment (0.45356 += 0.001) so it kept missing. This tween library looks great, I'll give it a go. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @PaulB Yeah that is why I use Less than/More than rather than equals, as that means it must be exactly equal to the target to stop, however if your target is 4.5 and you are incrementing by 0.451, you'll never hit it! Glad I could help, please accept my answer if it helps you so that other's can find the correct solution in the future :)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the THREE [AnimationMixer](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/animation/AnimationMixer). The function below sets up the animation. Example [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devnullnor/vr5mg04b/30/).

```
const createMoveAnimation = ({ mesh, startPosition, endPosition }) => {
  mesh.userData.mixer = new AnimationMixer(mesh);
  let track = new VectorKeyframeTrack(
    '.position',
    [0, 1],
    [
      startPosition.x,
      startPosition.y,
      startPosition.z,
      endPosition.x,
      endPosition.y,
      endPosition.z,
    ]
  );
  const animationClip = new AnimationClip(null, 5, [track]);
  const animationAction = mesh.userData.mixer.clipAction(animationClip);
  animationAction.setLoop(LoopOnce);
  animationAction.play();
  mesh.userData.clock = new Clock();
  this.animationsObjects.push(mesh);
};
```